# Using Jquery AJAX put method with the Google sheets API gives error 401

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to write to a Google Sheet using the API and JavaScript, the spreadsheet is set to be publicly visable but not publicly editable, hence the API key.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{SheetID}/values/A1%3AA200?includeValuesInResponse=false&valueInputOption=RAW&key={My API Key}",
   "values": messages,
error: function() {
    console.log("Error");
    }
});
```

when I run this code, the console logs "Error" like I asked it to when it gets an error, and the google API returns error 401.

My api key is set to have no restrictions while I build the site, its for private use btw so I'm not concerned about end security, but will add it anyways later.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm already using the API to get the data from the spread sheet for display purposes with no error, meanwhile I run into this error when trying to write to it.

Please forgive my poor english, I'm also brand new to AJAX.

Comment: as a workaround, you can use scripts.google.com to fetch the worksheet data

Comment: PUT method cannot be used by API key. API key can be used for GET method and the content is required to be shared publicly. So you can retrieve the values using API key. In your situation, please use the access token retrieved by OAuth2 or Service Account.